# How to use oracle sequence.nextval

Tags: database, oracle, sequence

I need to increment my id. I have to increment by using sequence in oracle database. When i use `INSERT INTO XXX (seq_xxx.nextval, ....)` i have error `invalid column name`.

EDIT: The problem was in capital letters `SEQ_XXX.NEXTVAL` is working fine.

Comment: Do you need to insert a new row or update an existing one? Also, if you have to insert a new row, [this](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF01604) is the right syntax

Comment: Unlike MySQL where VALUES is optional, in Oracle `VALUES` is required.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Insert Statement in Oracle:

```
insert into XXX (id, ...) values (seq_xxx.nextVal, ...)
```

**Note:**
(id, ...) = table column names